# What is the word for "composing of a single part"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I feel like this is on the tip of my tongue. What is the adjective for describing something as composing of a single part? e.g. "Your goals need not be [composed of a single part]."

Some possibilities that don't particularly ring true for me:

**Homogeneous**: I get the sense that "homogeneous" describes the qualia of a mixture, but the context I'm using it is not describing a mixture.

**Monolith**: This word's connotation seems to be more about the size of the object, not the composition of it.

**Simple**: This is the mathematical word for what I'm looking to describe, but this is a pretty technical and overloaded word that doesn't suit a layman audience, so I'm not inclined to use it.

Comment: Hmm, what about 'singular'?

Comment: simplex, monolithic, unifaceted, uniform, aligned

Comment: https://www.powerthesaurus.org/indivisible

Comment: *Monolithic* is not about size unless you are talking about stone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was thinking about *singular*, as mentioned in a comment, but, for me anyway, it produced an odd association when I used it in the sentence. (Both because of the fact that *singular* seems to clash with the plural word *goals* and because of its other sense of *unique*.)

What's needed is something that's an unambiguous "single" version of *multifaceted*.

Although it's not as common a word, I think a more suitable adjective (with a specific single sense—yes, that could be a pun) is [**unary**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/unary):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> : having, consisting of, or acting on a single element, item, or component : MONADIC

In other words:

> Your goals need not be **unary**.

While it seems to fit the exact meaning you're looking for, my only concern is that it may not also fit the layperson audience you describe.

---

Having said that, if you are amendable to having your example sentence rephrased, it would be more natural to say:

> Your goals need not serve a **single** purpose.

However, this does move the adjective from *goals* to the added word *purpose*.

Comment: 'unitary' is better here than 'unary'.